# ArangoDB set true or false by UPDATE

Tags: arangodb

i would like IF in to query. IF set i.eye 'true' then set 'false' by UPDATE

Example:

`FOR i IN plannavi
    FILTER i.user_key == @uk AND i._key == @key
        UPDATE i WITH {i.eye: i.eye == true ? false : true} IN plannavi`

What's the Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query should work, if you want to toggle `i.eye` you can either do what you did or this: `{i.eye: !i.eye}`.

If you're having issues, you may want to confirm the `i._key == @key` filter option, because if you are filtering on key, it wouldn't be expected to filter on another field.